# Unable to debug using Jython in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jython

I keep getting this error when I try to debug in PyCharm using Jython interpreter. Any idea why this appears?

```
pydev debugger: process 33616 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 141.2569) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 120, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 41, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
**IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '127.0.0.1'**
```

In this link is my run configuration:[run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMwvo.png)

Comment: Theorically, it is possible to use PyCharm to debug Jython: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools.  PyCharm supports all major Python implementations including Python 2.x and 3.x, Jython, IronPython, PyPy and Cython.  But I don't know how.

Comment: You might wanna try their bug tracker. They tend to be very responsive and helpful.https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY